# React Memory Efficiency

Tags: typescript, memory, react-tsx

I'm trying to make my react app as memory-efficient as possible.
I have this VacationCard component (TypeScript) which has many instances along the project :

```
interface CardProps {
    vacation: VacationData,
    userId : number
}

function VacationCard({vacation , userId}: CardProps) : JSX.Element {
    const [showFullDescription, setShowFullDescription] = useState(false);
    const { destination, imageName, description, isFollowing , vacationId , startDate , endDate} = vacation;
    const [isFollowed, setIsFollowed] = useState<boolean>(isFollowing === 1);

    // Handling follow requests:
    const handleFollow = async (): Promise<void> => {

        // If user us already following - execute unfollow
        if (isFollowed) {

            // Call service to unfollow vacation:
            vacationsService.unfollowVacation(vacationId , userId)
            .then(()=>setIsFollowed(false))
            .catch(err => notifyService.error(err));
        }
        else {
            // If user is not following , execute follow:
            vacationsService.followVacation(vacationId , userId)
            .then(()=>setIsFollowed(true))
            .catch(err => notifyService.error(err));
        }
    }

    const toggleDescription = (): void => {
        setShowFullDescription(!showFullDescription);
    };

    // If i gonna leave it this way. I will have to use useMemo hook.
    const getDescriptionPreview = (): string => {
        const words = description.split(' ');
        if (words.length <= 50) {
            return description;
        }
        return `${words.slice(0, 50).join(' ')}...`;
    };

    const getDescriptionFull = (): string => {
        return description;
    };
    

    return (
        <div className="VacationCard">

            <button onClick={handleFollow}>
                {isFollowed ? 'Unfollow' : 'Follow'} | {vacation.followersCount}
            </button>
            <p>{destination}</p>
            <img src={appConfig.vacationsImagesUrl + imageName} alt={destination} />
            <p>{format(new Date(startDate), 'd.M.yyyy')} - {format(new Date(endDate), 'd.M.yyyy')}</p>
            <p>{showFullDescription ? getDescriptionFull() : getDescriptionPreview()}</p>
            {description.length > 50 && (
                <button onClick={toggleDescription}>
                    {showFullDescription ? 'See Less' : 'See More'}
                </button>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

export default VacationCard;
```

This component is being called from this Vacations component (right at the bottom , but I've attached the whole component just in case):

```
function Vacations(): JSX.Element {

// Use navigate:
const navigate = useNavigate();

// Vacations use state:
const [vacations, setVacations] = useState<VacationData[]>([]);

// Filters use state:
const [filterOption, setFilterOption] = useState<string>("all");

// Get user id from auth store:
const userId : number = authStore.getState().user.userId;

// Logout
function logout(): void {
    authService.logout();
    notifyService.success("You Have been logged out");
    navigate("/login");
}

// Set the user's choice filter:
const handleFilters = (e : React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=>{
    setFilterOption(e.target.value);
}

// Filter vacation:
const filteredVacations = useMemo(()=>{

    switch (filterOption) {
        // all vacations
        case "all":
            return vacations;

        // Only followed vacations:
        case "followedOnly":
            return vacations.filter((v)=> v.isFollowing === 1);
        
        // Only upcoming vacations:
        case "upComingOnly":
            return vacations.filter((v)=> new Date(v.startDate) > new Date());

        // Only ongoing vacations:
        case "onGoingOnly":
            return vacations.filter((v)=> new Date(v.startDate) <= new Date() && new Date(v.endDate) >= new Date());
    }

} , [vacations , filterOption])


// When page is first loading
useEffect(()=>{

    // Get user state:
    const authState : AuthState = authStore.getState();

    // If user is not connected:
    if(!userId){
        notifyService.error("You must be logged in");
        navigate("/login");
        return;
    }

    // Call service and send back user id:
    vacationsService.getVacations(userId)
    .then(vacations => {
    setVacations(vacations);
    
    const unsubscribe = vacationsStore.subscribe(()=>{
    const duplicatedVacations = [...vacationsStore.getState().vacations];
    setVacations(duplicatedVacations);
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
})
.catch(err => {
    if(err.response!.status === 401){
        authService.logout();
        notifyService.error("You must be logged in");
        navigate('/login');
    }
    else{
        notifyService.error(err)
    }
});
}, []);

    return (
        <div className="Vacations">
            <div>

            <span className="Logout"><button onClick={logout}>Logout</button></span>

            <label>Filters: | </label>
            <label>
                All
                <input type="radio" name="options" value={"all"} onChange={handleFilters}
                defaultChecked
                />
            </label>
            <span> | </span>
            <label>
                Followed
                <input type="radio" name="options" value={"followedOnly"} onChange={handleFilters}/>
            </label>
            <span> | </span>
            <label>
                Up Comings
                <input type="radio" name="options" value={"upComingOnly"} onChange={handleFilters}/>
            </label>
            <span> | </span>
            <label>
                On Goings
                <input type="radio" name="options" value={"onGoingOnly"} onChange={handleFilters}/>
            </label>
            </div>
    
            <div className="Container">
            {filteredVacations.map(v => <VacationCard key={v.vacationId} vacation={v} userId={userId}/>)}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Vacations;
```

So I'm wondering whether it would be better to create a CardModel which holds all of the VacationCard functions in static mode , hopefully to help reduce memory usage , or if it's better to keep all of the VacationCard functions in the parent Vacations component and pass them as props (again , for efficiency purposes).

Answer (score 0):

You think about this too much. React do as much optimizations as possible out of the box. I've checked your code and don't see any critical problems or functions in `VacationCard` that should be optimized...

You use state so functions should be defined inside your component anyway, or you can use hooks approach, but don't overplay with that because you logic seems completed and holistic, don't split it too much for better code readability.

Im my opinion only one function can be extracted. If `getDescriptionPreview` is used only for `VacationCard` you can move it outside of function OR if you are going to reuse it somewhere else move it to your helpers/utilities.

If you want memory efficient app use `useMemo` and `useCallback` in cases you have huge calculations or re-renders. Keep in mind that function/object that isn't wrapped in `useCallback`/`useMemo` and passed into the props causes re-render each time. Any primitives are memoized by default by React.

Also don't pay attention to small functions that are isolated in one component, you won't win much speed. Write more logic in `useEffect`s and everything will be all right.

Comment: thank you , this did got my mind fixed about it